# Unhandled Exception When Executing SQL Server INSERT

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have written code in C# and integrated it with SQL Server, but each time I run it I keep getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ';'.'

My code is this:

```
private void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connectiontring =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connData"].ConnectionString;

    string querystring = "INSERT INTO [Table] VALUES(@Name, @Gender, @Age, @Course, @Department, @Program, @Address, @PostCode, @Email;";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectiontring))
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(querystring, connection);
        connection.Open();

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", tblName.Text);
        ...
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Email", tbllMail.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteReader();

        tblName.Text = "";
        ...
        tbllMail.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that it's always recommended to include column names in insert statements: `insert into [Table] (Name, Gender, Age...) VALUES (@Name, @Gender, @Age...)`. Also, `SqlCommand` is an `IDisposable`, and also, [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Haha.. What's with the AddwithValue?

Comment: That's a link, read the article...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server is right. Add a closing paren after the list of values:

```
string querystring = "insert into [Table] VALUES(@Name, ..., @Email);";
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `;` in the query string in place where `)` should appear. Correct query string is:

```
 string querystring = 
    "insert into [Table] VALUES " +
    "   (@Name, @Gender, @Age, @Course, @Department, @Program, " +
    "    @Address, @PostCode, @Email)";
```